# How do I convert '2019-02-22T12:11:00Z' to 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS' format in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-pipe, angular-date-format

I am working on some API clockify API integration. I am getting all time entries from the API. in the response I am getting start & end time of the task in the `2019-02-22T12:11:00Z`.

I want to convert above date format in `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format. I have used date pipe for this {{item.timeInterval.start | date: `dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a z`}} but its not working. it displays the same.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using parse into `Date` object like this -

```
parseIntoDate(date){
    return Date.parse(date)
}

<p>{{parseIntoDate(item.timeInterval.start) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a z'}}</p>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3zgmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: the date format was wrong  so we don't need to parse

Comment: `{{"2019-02-22T12:11:00Z"| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a z'}}` 

Comment: @malbarmawi amaze what if in above statement date format is wrong?

Comment: Haha Anyways loved smilies

Comment: Date pipe will parse to date by default before start generate the formated date https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.6/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L174  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.6/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L669 

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is wrong  any wrong format will not parse as an example YYYY format will return YYYY but yyyy will return the year 2019 check the documentation for the all format option [her](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options)

```
{{'2019-02-22T12:11:00Z' | date : "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss"}}
<br>
{{'2019-02-22T12:11:00Z' | date : "short"}}
<br>
{{'2019-02-22T12:11:00Z' | date : "full"}}
<br>
{{'2019-02-22T12:11:00Z' | date : "yyy"}}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmygfj)

Answer (score 0):

Date in my TS file -

myDate = '2019-02-22T12:11:00Z';

in the html

{{myDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS'}}

Comment: MM mean month `HH:MM:SS` => `HH:mm:ss` 

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your string into a Date object when you receive the data from the API. Just use `item.timeInterval.start = new Date(item.timeInterval.start)`